# SQL Group By Number Of Users Within Range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which will return the number of users in table transactions who have earned between $100 and $200

```
SELECT COUNT(users.id)
FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = transactions.user_id
WHERE transactions.amount > 100 AND transactions.amount < 200
```

The above query returns the correct result below:

```
COUNT(users.id)
559
```

I would like to extend it so that the query can return data in the following format:

```
COUNT(users.id)    :     amount
1678               :     0-100
559                :     100-200
13                 :     200-300
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just three queries?

Comment: This is just an simplified example, in reality I will need a lot more ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression inside of your aggregate function which will get the result in columns:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(case when amount >= 0 and amount <= 100 then users.id end) Amt0_100,
  COUNT(case when amount >= 101 and amount <= 200 then users.id end) Amt101_200,
  COUNT(case when amount >= 201 and amount <= 300 then users.id end) Amt201_300
FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN users 
  ON users.id = transactions.user_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22afb/3)

You will notice that I altered the ranges from 0-100, 101-200, 201-300 otherwise you will have user ids being counted twice on the 100, 200 values.

If you want the values in rows, then you can use:

```
select count(u.id), 
  CASE 
    WHEN amount >=0 and amount <=100 THEN '0-100'
    WHEN amount >=101 and amount <=200 THEN '101-200'
    WHEN amount >=201 and amount <=300 THEN '101-300'
  END Amount
from transactions t
left join users u
  on u.id = t.user_id
group by 
  CASE 
    WHEN amount >=0 and amount <=100 THEN '0-100'
    WHEN amount >=101 and amount <=200 THEN '101-200'
    WHEN amount >=201 and amount <=300 THEN '101-300'
  END
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22afb/4)

But if you have many ranges that you need to calculate the counts on, then you might want to consider creating a table with the ranges, similar to the following:

```
create table report_range
(
  start_range int,
  end_range int
);

insert into report_range values
(0, 100),
(101, 200), 
(201, 300);
```

Then you can use this table to join to your current tables and group by the range values:

```
select count(u.id) Total, concat(start_range, '-', end_range) amount
from transactions t
left join users u
  on u.id = t.user_id
left join report_range r
  on t.amount >= r.start_range
  and t.amount<= r.end_range
group by concat(start_range, '-', end_range);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8a22/4).

If you don't want to create a new table with the ranges, then you can always use a derived table to get the same result:

```
select count(u.id) Total, concat(start_range, '-', end_range) amount
from transactions t
left join users u
  on u.id = t.user_id
left join
(
  select 0 start_range, 100 end_range union all
  select 101 start_range, 200 end_range union all
  select 201 start_range, 300 end_range 
) r
  on t.amount >= r.start_range
  and t.amount<= r.end_range
group by concat(start_range, '-', end_range);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22afb/1)

Comment: Buckets like this are where EXCEL can help with writing sql.

Comment: That's really nice, how does it compare to using several queries, in terms of speed?

Comment: Also, don't you need to use the keyword "as" ?

Comment: @DanyCaissy `as` is not required

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use a case/when statement in your group by.

```
SELECT
-- NB this must match your group by statement exactly 
-- otherwise you will get an error
CASE 
    WHEN amount <= 100
    THEN '0-100'
    WHEN amount <= 200
    THEN '100-200'
    ELSE '201+'
END Amount,
COUNT(*)
FROM  
    transactions
GROUP BY
CASE 
    WHEN amount <= 100
    THEN '0-100'
    WHEN amount <= 200
    THEN '100-200'
    ELSE '201+'
END
```

If you plan on using the grouping elsewhere, it probably makes sense to define it as a scalar function (it will also look cleaner)

e.g.

```
SELECT 
AmountGrouping(amount),
COUNT(*)
FROM  
transactions
GROUP BY
AmountGrouping(amount)
```

If you want to be fully generic:

```
SELECT
    concat(((amount DIV 100) * 100),'-',(((amount DIV 100) + 1) * 100)) AmountGroup,
    COUNT(*)
FROM  
    transactions
GROUP BY
    AmountGroup
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22afb/9)

Comment: Note that this is a lot more generic than the other answer, as you can define your function to do any type of grouping and you will get rows instead of columns

Comment: I was actually in the process of updating mine with a generic answer that uses either a table of the ranges or a derived table.

Comment: The one thing is you are using SQL Server syntax for MySQL tagged question, you might want to update it

Comment: Ahh good point :)  On the road now, so I'll update it tomorrow. Nice catch

Comment: Yeah - we were saying the same thing, except in different languages. Gotta love it when integer math works _for_ you for a change ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bilbo, I tried to be creative and found a very nice solution [ for those who love math (like me) ]
It's always surprising when MySQL integer division operator solves our problems.

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `stackoverflow3`;
CREATE SCHEMA `stackoverflow3`;
USE `stackoverflow3`;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "-");

CREATE TABLE transactions(
  id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  amount INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id));

INSERT users () VALUES (),(),();
INSERT transactions (user_id,amount)
  VALUES (1,120),(2,270),(3, 350),
    (2,500), (1,599), (1,550), (3,10),
    (3,20), (3,30), (3,50), (3,750);

SELECT
  COUNT(t.id),
  CONCAT(
    ((t.amount DIV 100)*100)," to ",((t.amount DIV 100 + 1)*100-1)
  ) AS amount_range
FROM transactions AS t
GROUP BY amount_range;
```

Awaiting your questions, Mr. Baggins.